# Visual Studio 2015 hangs after some seconds

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015.
When I start the IDE, it hangs after a short while, and I need to kill the process in Task Manager. Sometimes, I can open a project before it freezes, but then it usually freezes some time after that.

- My OS: Windows 7
- VS version: 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Screen shot from ProcessExplorer:
(red marks numbers that keep climbing, the rest are not increasing)
[image: Screen shot from Process Explorer]

I have created a dump file, but can't debug it...

Can someone please help me?

**EDIT: Feb 2017** :
New PC (Windows 10) and newer version (14.0.25431.01 Update 3) do NOT give the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New PC (Windows 10) and newer version (14.0.25431.01 Update 3) do NOT give the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago.

First, I'd recommend you to disable all extensions you're not interested in using of.

Second, many of VS issues is because of Node.js Tools. Though latest version of which fixes many of them, I highly recommend you to uninstall it if you're not planning to develop node-based apps.

Finally, there's still a lot of performance issues with VS, so we can only hope that Microsoft will fix them in the future.

Comment: ok, good. But how do I disable extensions ? It normally freezes before I can open any other windows...

Comment: @thomas you should to try to do it really fast:)
Maybe your internet connection is slow. Disconnect it for now. It's may cause VS to freezing.
You can try to reinstall VS. When I had the same problems, I've just reinstalled whole VS and all the issues are gone.

Comment: Actually, Fiddler gives no feedback on anything problematic about internet connection or any problems to any sites...